# Running Composer without using sudo (tried changed owner and permissions)

Tags: 14.04, sudo, root

Every time I run composer (e.g., `sudo composer install, sudo composer self-update` etc.) I need to run this with sudo as the owner of the file is root.

However every time I use the composer with sudo root owns the vendor folder and then I have to change the owner of that folder/privileges from root to www-data.

What is the best way to fix this so I do not have to run sudo every time?

Change the owner of `/usr/local/bin/composer` from root to www-data?

Is this the ideal way to handle this to avoid having to change ownership and assign permission every time I use sudo `composer install`?

**Edit:**
The permissions for composer are currently `-rwxr-xr-x`. And I've tried switching the owner of `/usr/local/bin/composer` over to `www-data:www-data` with permissions set to 775, and still I can't run composer without running `sudo`.

Answer (score 14):

If "everyone" is allowed to read and execute composer, you don't need to use sudo:

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/local/bin/composer
```

Since you already executed composer at least once as `root`, composers (per-user-)cache directory is now owned by root and therefore isn't writable by your normal user.

```
sudo chown -R lamp:lamp /home/lamp/.composer
```

will fix the file-owner.

Comment: I've tried this and I'm still unable to run `composer self-update` without using sudo. Do I need to use 775?

Comment: Well self-update won't work with 755 but does this matter? self-update is nothing you'll need to execute every day, just update it once every 2 weeks or so (with sudo of course).

Comment: Tried `composer update` and this also doesn't work with those permissions. I still have to use sudo first. This is the error I get `file_put_contents(/home/lamp/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: ooh, yes, you already used "sudo" to update some of your deps, i think "/home/lamp/.composer/" is owned by root, just delete this folder (its just a cache), then it should work without sudo. (Or change ownership: `chown -R lamp:lamp /home/lamp/.composer` )

Comment: That did the trick, went with changing the owner to lamp. Can you update your answer and I'll accept it? Thanks takusl

Comment: Works fine. Just a note, my Composer was in  /usr/local/bin/composer

Answer (score 6):

I found this command useful to run composer as www-data:

```bsh
sudo su -l www-data -s /bin/bash -c "cd $PWD; composer install"
```

reference: https://commandroll.com/command/run-command-as-www-data-using-su

Answer (score 5):

I have been dealing with this issue for weeks.

I think the solution is to run composer self-update with the -H

```
sudo -H composer self-update
```

Before doing this be sure to remove the .composer directories in root and the home directory of the user you wish to execute composer.

```
sudo rm -rf /root/.composer
sudo rm -rf /home/ubuntu/.composer
```

Running sudo composer self-update without the -H flag will create ~/.composer that is owned by root and will prevent other composer commands to have permission errors.

```
composer config
composer install
```

In my opinion calling sudo composer self-update should not create files owned by root in the current users home directory.

Note if you follow these instructions on Ubuntu 14.04 composer will place the cache in:

```
 ~/.cache/composer
```

Rather than:

```
~/.composer/cache
```

This is because of the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR environment variable defined in Ubuntu 14.04 but doesn't seem to be defined in Ubuntu 12.04

[A related discussion here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4866)

Comment: This doesn't help if you're already running the most current version of composer.

`$ sudo -H composer self-update

$ You are already using composer version 1.3.0 (stable channel).`

Comment: @Cragmonkey - I was running the latest version of composer but just removing the `~/.composer` folder seems to solve the problem.